# How to get a row for a given date from a column

Tags: mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy

Using `sqlalchemy`, I dumped a `pandas` `dataframe` to a `mysql` `table` like this:

```
dataClose = data[['Date', 'Close']]
print(dataClose)


# Convert dataframe to sql table
dataClose.to_sql('data', engine, index=False)
```

This produces the schema below, **how do I get the a `row` for a given `Date`?**:

For example, if I say:

```
select * from data limit 1;
```

I get a bunch of stuff that looks like this (abbreviated):

```
    +---------------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+...| ('Date', '')        | ('Close', 'A')     | ('Close', 'AAL')  | ('Close', 'AAP')   | ('Close', 'AAPL')  | ('Close', 'ABBV')  | ('Close', 'ABC')   | ('Close', 'ABMD') | ('Close', 'ABT')  | ('Close', 'ACN')  | ('Close', 'ADBE')...  |
+---------------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+
| 2021-03-01 00:00:00 | 124.12773132324219 | 21.18000030517578 | 161.61163330078125 | 127.57331085205078 | 105.92682647705078 | 102.78999328613281 |  324.260009765625 | 121.3011245727539 | 256.6390686035156 | 469.57000732421875 | 157.92227172851562 | 56.9865608215332 | 175.76467895507812 | 284.2699890136719 |...
```

This is the schema:

```
mysql> show columns from data;
+--------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field              | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ('Date', '')       | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ('Close', 'A')     | double   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ('Close', 'AAL')   | double   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ('Close', 'AAP')   | double   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ('Close', 'AAPL')  | double   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
```

**EDIT 1:**

This doesn't work:

```
mysql> select * from data where DATE(('Date', '')) = '2021-03-01' limit 1;
ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)
mysql>
```

Comment: select * from data where DATE(`('Date', '')`) = given_date limit 1;

Comment: @radocaw see Edit 1. It gives an error

Comment: You can't see it, but ('Date', '') is wrapped in backticks (`)

Comment: … as in DATE(\`('Date', '')\`)

Comment: TIL that MySQL will actually let you create a column named `('Date', '')`. Wow. In any case, you'll definitely want to change those column names; they're *nasty!*